# Swift "namespaces" in mixed objective-c project not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, namespaces

I have a custom framework `MyFramework` written in objective-c, where I, in an objective-c category on `UIColor`, define a method thus:

```
+ (instancetype)my_colorWithRed:(uint8_t)red 
                          green:(uint8_t)green 
                           blue:(uint8_t)blue 
                          alpha:(uint8_t)alpha NS_SWIFT_NAME(init(red:green:blue:alpha:));
```

I use `NS_SWIFT_NAME` to give it a proper Swift name. However, the declaration of the Swift name is identical with a method already present on `UIColor` in `UIKit`, namely:

```
init(red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat)
```

Now, if I add a Swift file in my main app — a mixed objective-c and swift project that links to `MyFramework` — and write the following:

```
UIColor(red: 1, blue: 0, green: 0, alpha: 1)
```

the `UIKit` version of the method is called. But if I write:

```
MyFramework.UIColor(red: 1, blue: 0, green: 0, alpha: 1)
```

the `UIKit` version of the method is still called.

So I'm wonder why:

- building the app without prefixing the method with a module name does not give me any warnings or errors even though the method is ambiguous. I was under the impression that I would get warnings if this happened.
- specifying `MyFramework` to scope the method doesn’t have effect.

In the Swift file I do not need to import `UIKit` or `MyFramework` because they are already imported via the Swift bridging header; not directly, but indirectly through some header files that in turn imports them. Could that be what is causing the issue? Or is it because it’s a mixed objective-c and Swift project? Or is it because this is a method on a category?

### UPDATE

Answer from Tarun Tyagi made aware of the parameter types.
Specifying the types makes it work:

```
UIColor(red: UInt8(149), green: UInt8(45), blue: UInt8(152))
```

This calls the method in `MyFramework`. That means that using Integers in the call as I initially did:

```
UIColor(red: 1, blue: 0, green: 0, alpha: 1)
```

matches `UIKit`’s `init(red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat)` instead of `MyFramework`’s `convenience init(red: UInt8, green: UInt8, blue: UInt8)`.

If I create a new category method that takes Int

```
+ (instancetype)my_colorWithIntRed:(NSInteger)red green:(NSInteger)green blue:(NSInteger)blue alpha:(NSInteger)alpha NS_SWIFT_NAME(init(red:green:blue:alpha:));
```

and then call `UIColor(red: 1, blue: 0, green: 0, alpha: 1)` from the main app, the call matches that method.

Adding `UIKit` or `MyFramework` to qualify the call makes no difference. The matching is only based on the argument types, regardless of which module it's defined in. That is, calling:

```
UIKit.UIColor(red: 1, blue: 0, green: 0, alpha: 1)
```

does not give an error and the method in `MyFramework` is still called.

If I create a initializer in the `MyFramework` category of `UIColor` that exactly matches the one in `UIKit.UIColor`:

```
+ (instancetype)my_colorWithFloatRed:(CGFloat)red green:(CGFloat)green blue:(CGFloat)blue alpha:(CGFloat)alpha NS_SWIFT_NAME(init(red:green:blue:alpha:));
```

then there’s simply no Swift version generated.

If I create the same method in a swift extension of UIColor instead

```
@objc public convenience init(red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat) {
    ...
}
```

then I get an expected error:

> Initializer 'init(red:green:blue:alpha:)' with Objective-C selector 'initWithRed:green:blue:alpha:' conflicts with previous declaration with the same Objective-C selector

But when I remove the @obj to only make the method available in Swift I get no error, which indicates that Swift allows to have colliding method names in extensions defined by different modules.

So I make this call from from my main app:

```
UIColor(red: CGFloat(0.5), green: CGFloat(0.5), blue: CGFloat(1.0), alpha: CGFloat(1.0))
```

but I still get no error about ambiguous methods, and the `UIKit` version is called. Further, qualifying with:

```
MyFramework.UIColor(red: CGFloat(0.5), green: CGFloat(0.5), blue: CGFloat(1.0), alpha: CGFloat(1.0))
```

again makes no difference.

So I still don’t understand how implicit namespacing in Swift is supposed to work with extensions. It seems that it's not supported. I read through the Swift programing guide on [extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html) and there’s no mention about this.

Answer (score 2):

**Building the app without prefixing the method with a module name does not give me any warnings or errors even though the method is ambiguous. I was under the impression that I would get warnings if this happened**

> This seems like -
>
> A. Either it should be translated in Swift to use `UInt8` instead of `CGFloat` so it is different based on type of input.
>
> B. Or it shouldn't allow to use `init(red:green:blue:alpha:)` inside `NS_SWIFT_NAME` since it collides with already existing initializer.
>
> Neither A nor B happens, so it seems to be a bug. You should file a radar to investigate this further.

**Specifying MyFramework to scope the method doesn’t have effect**

> `UIColor` isn't owned by your custom framework and you are only extending it. It's your responsibility to name the methods uniquely.
>   A possible name would be `my_color(red:green:blue:alpha:)` inside `NS_SWIFT_NAME` to make it unique.
>
> Clearly your naming `init(red:green:blue:alpha:)` collides with `UIKit` standard initializer and in case you don't get a compiler warning and are able to run, `UIKit` variant wins over your custom one.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT 1: Reference**
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html

Adding it as a screenshot here since a link might break in a future revision.
[image]

Although the reference is for Objective-C and not Swift extension, this is valid for `UIColor` extension because all UIKit is still Objective-C as of now.

Comment: Do you have a reference to a source from Apple or Swift team that states that method names in extensions must be made unique?

Comment: @Karmeye Please have a look at the *EDIT 1: Reference* in the answer. Thanks.

Comment: I know this is the case with Objective-c categories. I was asking specifically about Swift extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Try prefixing your frameworks classes with something unique. Call it MyFrameworkUIColor

Comment: Yes that will work. But the question is about why explicitly qualifying with the module name does not call the correct method.